# How to transfer Time format "hh:mm tt" from Datagridview data cell to a datetimepicker?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to do the following:where StartTime EndTime are a Datetimepicker

```
   StartTime.Value = "01/01/2010 " & DGVEvemts(1, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("hh:mm tt")

    EndTime.Value = "01/01/2010 " & DGVEvemts(2, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: `.Value` is DateTime object. You can set the `CustomFormat` property to `"hh:mm tt"` and set a DateTime value. What is the data type of Columns `1` and `2`? Does you DGV allow do add new Rows (you're trying to retrieve a value from row `DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1`)?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `Strings` at all. DO NOT convert between `DateTime` and `String` for any reason that doesn't involve requiring a `String` as an output, e.g. display or serialisation, or as an input, e.g. reading a file or user input at the console. If you are starting with a `DateTime` and you want to end with a `DateTime` then there should be no intermediate `Strings` involved.

Assuming that your `DataGridView` contains `DateTime` values, you can do this:

```vb
StartTime.Value = #1/01/2010# + CDate(DGVEvemts(1, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1)).TimeOfDay
```

That creates a `Date` literal, gets the `Date` from the grid, gets the time portion from that `Date` and adds it to the literal. If the time in the grid might contain partial minutes and you only want whole minutes, you can do this:

```vb
Dim dt = CDate(DGVEvemts(1, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1))

StartTime.Value = #1/01/2010# + New TimeSpan(dt.Hours, dt.Minutes, 0)
```

Comment: visual studio Can' convert the datagridview cell contents to time or date in both cases

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelaziz, I don't know whether that's a statement or a question and I don't know what it's supposed to mean. The only conversion a `DataGridView` does is to a `String` for the purposes of display. The data in the grid is the type it is so you need to treat it as that type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    If DGVEvemts.Rows.Count < 1 Then Return
   
    RecStTxt.Text = "01/01/2010 " & DGVEvemts(1, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1).Value.ToString()
    RecEndTxt.Text = "01/01/2010 " & DGVEvemts(2, DGVEvemts.Rows.Count - 1).Value.ToString()
    StartTime.Value = RecStTxt.Text
    EndTime.Value = RecEndTxt.Text
```